# Why are Javascript closures called secure

Tags: javascript, closures

In one of his [videos](http://video.yahoo.com/video/play?vid=111595) (at around 1 min 25 seconds. The clock in the video goes backwards, so it's at -27:45), Douglas Crockford mentions that Javascript closures are a source of enormous expressive power and unlike other power constructs are also secure. He specifically mentions that in Javascript closures constraint scope, which makes them more secure.

Can someone help me with a few examples which show how scoping rules of Javascript closures make them more secure than other languages which have closures. Also are there any other things which make Javascript closures more secure than their counterparts in other languages?

Comment: Good question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are "secure" in the sense that only code *within* the lexical scope of the closure can *directly* access the variables of the closures function-scope. I recommend reading the [Jibbering Closure Notes](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/), in general.

Any "leaked" object may still introduce an data-manipulation/side-effect point. The closures in ECMAScript are no more "secure" than in any other language with similar closure semantics -- in this sense "secure" means "private variable access". On the other hand, some languages already have more controlled visibility modifiers of members (e.g. Java or C# with private/public distinctions).

This is, of course, if one considers JavaScript objects which "merely" rely on prototypes to be "insecure". (If someone uses my code incorrectly, let them -- and if it it breaks, let them burn ;-)

Personally I find Mr. Crockford a fine evangelist -- but not for my religion ;-) One can say all sorts of good thing about X without properly analyzing it in relationship to Y.

Comment: Amen to that. Love to read Douglas's stuff but don't take a lot of his advice. Too much of a purist. I start private prototype properties with an underscore, if someone chooses to mess with it, they're on their own. But at least they can get it to do what they want. Whereas in 'safe' languages, if the lib is broken, you have to wait for the lib writer to fix it

Comment: The `private` modifier is probably secure in languages like C# and Java where the VM can provide this security. In C++, on the other hand, it's very easy to access the `private` data of an object, e.g. using a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 3):

Closures give you the ability to encapsulate (hide) data, as desirable with object oriented design.

The ability to effectively define "private" variables and publish a "public" interface  makes it less likely that a programmer will misuse the object - i.e. mess with the data value directly and yield unexpected side-effects.

```
// returns an object that does not itself possess "var a"
// The closure gives indirect access to a, via the public getter and setter.
function f() {
   var a = 1;

   return {
      getA: function() {
         return a;
      },
      setA: function( A ) {
         a = A;
      }
   };
}

var MyObj = new f();

alert(MyObj.a); // --> undefined
alert(MyObj.getA()); // --> 1

MyObj.setA(5);
alert(MyObj.getA()); // --> 5
```

### [EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/ehasi3/3)